# Python Locating the Binary Path to Add to System Wide Paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I am creating a bash script to setup an environment automatically for MacOS. However I am struggling at finding the path to the python bin directory.

For example, when install pipenv via, `python3 -m pip install pipenv`, I get a warning specifying that `WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin' which is not on PATH.`

I need a method to automatically grab this path to add it to either `/.bash_profile` or `/.zshenv` depending on the environment.

Many recommendation online say to use, `$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin`, however on certain MacOS environments (like github actions), this path is located in `/Library/` as specified above and therefore does not work.

I can install pipenv with `sudo -H python3 -m pip install pipenv` but this does not solve my issue as future bins will not be accessible either.

I can optionaly parse the warning message to grab the path but I do not find this to clean and rather have a command I can run which outputs the results.